# C++ template argument which is already "known"

Tags: c++, templates

This question may be a well answered one but unfortunately I don't know the correct terminology to ask it properly, so...

```
template <class _Cp, bool _IsConst, typename _Cp::__storage_type = 0> class __bit_iterator;
```

Could someone explain the last template argument here?  The only thing I can infer is that if the parameter specified for _Cp has a sub-type __storage_type then any use of _Cp::__storage_type in the template will resolve to that.  If it doesn't then does that mean _Cp::__storage_type resolves to 0?  This seems really perverse to me (or likely wrong after a bit of experimentation).

Explanation along with correct terminology and C++ reference would be appreicated.

For interest, this code was pulled from libc++.

Comment: Just for the record: that looks like library code, do not use names starting with `_X` for any upper case letter `X` or having double underscores in the name `__`, as those are reserved. --completely unrelated to your question :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas He said, that this code is part of the `libc++`.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: And David said "completely unrelated to your question". He's leaving an advisory note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class template `__bit_iterator` takes three arguments:

- a class `_Cp`
- a boolean `_IsConst`
- an object of type `_Cp::__storage_type` (presumably an integer) that is given no name

  - this argument is optional and defaults to the expression `0`

The purpose of the third argument (since it is unnamed and thus cannot be used inside the definition of `__bit_iterator`) appears to be only to require that the class `_Cp` has a member type `__storage_type` that is compatible with the expression `0`. If it does not, that instantiation (with that `_Cp`), cannot compile.

Comment: Thanks.  The piece I was missing is that _Cp::__storage_type is an unnamed param.  With that info it fits back into my understanding of templates (thankfully!).  Not the first time I've been caught out by anonymous types in C++!

Comment: What's a *member type*? Is that a type definition within a class? Or a "member of type" which doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: @luk32: Yes, a type definition within a class. That could be an alias (`using`, `typedef`) or a nested UDT (`class`, `struct`). It's a member type, c.f. member function, member variable.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Thanks I asked because only thing I found was 2yo+ SO question. I don't think this term is defined anywhere even as a concept such as *PODType* or *TriviallyConstructible*, etc. Yet it is used on certain occasions, I wondered if there is a proper definition somewhere.

Comment: @luk32: Just scanned the standard; can't find one.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class _Cp, bool _IsConst, typename _Cp::__storage_type = 0>
class __bit_iterator;
```

`__bit_iterator` is a class template. This template takes three arguments.

1. `_Cp`, which is a type.
2. `_IsConst`, which is a boolean value.
3. The last parameter is unnamed and is a value (just like `_IsConst`). Type of this parameter is type/typedef declared in `_Cp` and named `__storage_type`.

If you are confused by `typename` keyword: `typename` is [a method for indicating that a dependent name is a type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename#A_method_for_indicating_that_a_dependent_name_is_a_type).

`_Cp` is template argument and can be any type. Even a type, that doesn't contain anything like `__storage_type`. That's why we must tell compiler, that such thing should exist there and is a type/typedef. If this requirement is not fulfilled, compile-time error will be raised.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a slightly stricter requirement than just requiring that _Cp has a member type __storage_type.  As Lightning Racis in Obrit points out, it's slightly stricter in that it requires not only such a type but also that it can be assigned an int (with the usual C++ rules of implicit conversion).  In general you would be able to guarantee existence of such a subtype just by using it in the template definition.  Although if you had some strange class where you needed to guarantee that type existed but never used it then I guess you'd need some additional trickery :)

Comment: Thanks re the unnamed bit btw.  As commented in Lightning Racis in Obrit's answer, that's the trick I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class _Cp, bool _IsConst, typename _Cp::__storage_type = 0> 
class __bit_iterator;
```

That looks like a non-type template argument (not different from the previous `_IsConst` argument) that is initialized with a 0 if not user provided.  A possible specialization of that template could be:

```
struct X { typedef int __storage_type; };
__bit_iterator<X, false> bi;
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
__bit_iterator<X, false, X::__storage_type(0)> bi;
```

which is really equivalent (since `X::__storage_type` is `int`) to:

```
__bit_iterator<X, false, 0> bi;
```